# how to include timer in my program?

Tags: android, timer

i need to include timer in my application.i just gone through the example given in the sites.and tried to implement that in my program.but the thing is i dont know how to work with timer.in my program i want to start the timer on a button click.timer has to show in the screen.but the screen is a canvas(when we click on button it loads a canvas) with moving objects.when two objects collide timer has to stop and has to show the value in a message box.given below is my main activity code.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = MyActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public static Timer myTimer;
private Button startbtn;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
    startbtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.startbtn);
    startbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

               // making it full screen
                getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                // set our MainGamePanel as the View
                setContentView(new MainGamePanel(getApplicationContext()));
                Log.d(TAG, "View added");

        }
    });

   myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TimerMethod();
        }

    }, 0, 1000);

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Destroying...");
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Stopping...");
    super.onStop();
}
private void TimerMethod()
{
    //This method is called directly by the timer
    //and runs in the same thread as the timer.

    //We call the method that will work with the UI
    //through the runOnUiThread method.
    this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
}

private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

    //This method runs in the same thread as the UI.               

    //Do something to the UI thread here

    }
};

      }
```

i know how to check collision.i need only timer part like starting timer,showing on the screen and stopping it from another class.can anybody help me...plz....

Comment: your code already has the timer and timer task implemented. So whats the problem?

Comment: ijust copied that code from a site. i dnt knw how can i do the remaining things like showing the timer in the screen and stoping it when the objects collide..

Comment: nobody have answer for my question?????? :(

Comment: https://github.com/search?langOverride=&language=Java&q=timer&repo=&start_value=1&type=Repositories&x=0&y=0 A collection of different timers done. check them out.

Answer (score 1):

Use this the code will be repeated after one second and timer will run for 30sec

```
new CountdownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
   finish();
   }
}.start();
```